# Is it possible? Contract to split inputs amongst x addresses with a "reserve gas tank" for the next time it's called

Tags: contract-design, mining

I'm thinking along the lines of this previous poster [How can i automatically divide payments from mining](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4133/how-can-i-automatically-divide-payments-from-mining?answertab=active#tab-top)

Would it be possible to add some type of gas reserve to the contract? Ideally load it up for the next time it's called and have the ability to add to it at anytime to avoid potentially having inputs returned to the mining pool that sent them? Or maybe a situation where it auto-deducts enough gas from the division stage to fuel it's next input execution?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

First, because gas is not a (explicit) currency/token that one can store.

One could store instead ethers and use them for gas, but the underlying layer of the system already makes the separation between gas and ethers for the tx sender, it is not really possible to solve this from the contract itself at execution time.