# Is this the "correct" way of distributing uneven fractions of an ETH balance?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Some friends and I built a mining rig together, each contributing different amounts of fiat to the endeavor. I'm adapting the contract from [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4133/how-can-i-automatically-divide-payments-from-mining/4135#4135) to receive ETH from MiningPoolHub and distribute it to our separate addresses according to how much fiat we put into the initial cost of the rig. Have I gone about this the correct way?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;
contract SplitPayment
{
    address public A = 0xAAA; 
    uint256 public A_share  = 111111111;

    address public B  = 0xBBB;
    uint256 public B_share  = 222222222;

    address public C = 0xCCC;
    uint256 public C_share = 666666667;

    function sendPayment(address person, uint256 raw_share) private 
    {
        uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
        person.transfer(balance * raw_share / 1000000000);
    }
    function() payable public
    {
        sendPayment(A, A_share);
        sendPayment(B, B_share);
        sendPayment(C, C_share);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;
contract SplitPayment
{
    uint constant shareSum = 1000000000;

    address public A = 0xaaa...; 
    uint256 public A_share  = 111111111;

    address public B = 0xbbb...;
    uint256 public B_share  = 222222222;

    address public C = 0xccc...;

    function() payable public
    {
        uint256 balance = address(this).balance;

        uint toA = (balance * A_share) / shareSum;
        uint toB = (balance * B_share) / shareSum;
        uint toC = balance - (toA + toB);

        A.transfer(toA);

        B.transfer(toB);

        C.transfer(toC);

        assert(address(this).balance == 0);
    }
}
```